# When defining class attributes, which method of writing is more "Pythonic"?

Tags: python, class

I do this fairly frequently, and maybe it's bad design and there's a better way to do it, but I haven't ever had any issue.

When defining an object with a parent and assigning an attribute of that object to an attribute of the parent, which of these methods of writing is more "Pythonic"?

Assuming we are doing something like...

```
class SomeParent:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class SomeChild { ... }

parentObj = SomeParent(value="foo")
childObj = SomeChild(parent=parentObj)
```

Would the "proper" way to write the `__init__` for `SomeChild` be...

```
class SomeChild:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = parent.value
```

Or...

```
class SomeChild:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.value = self.parent.value
```

The only difference being the use of `self` when defining `value` on the child object. Obviously, they both (seemingly) work exactly the same, does it even matter which is used? Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: I wouldn't store the value in child at all

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do, but it seems like you probably want to use proper inheritance with `super()` and `class SomeChild(SomeParent):`

Comment: Generally, prefer composition over inheritance. So that's good. But copying a value over multiple objects is bad practice. What if you update one and forget to update the other?

Comment: The only case I could think of where it would make since to store the parent's `value` on the child is if there was something weird about the lookup: Is `value` going to be referenced much more often from the child than the other attributes & methods of parent, or are direct references to `parent` unreasonably slow / computationally intensive?  Is `parent.value` a regularly-changing quantity, and you want `child.value = {parent.value at the time child was instantiated}`?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. We don't deal with matters of opinion here, as this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: @mousetail The only time I would do this is if the value were static.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Apologies, I figured this was a matter of coding style, and considering the coding style tag is marked as "do not use", I wasn't sure where else to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this more cleanly with a property:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.a.value


assert B(A(2)).value == 2
```

This way, `B.value` will automatically update with `a.value`.

Note: I purposefully don't use the names "parent" and "child" which would imply inheritence. You are not using inheritence.

Comment: This is something I hadn't considered, great solution to my non-problem!